# on the 'immutability' of tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

If tuples are supposed to be immutable (which are in most cases), why can we change their data in the following way :

```
tuple = (1, 2, 3)

tuple += (4, 5)

print (tuple) #outputs (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: You didn't mutate a tuple', you created a new one

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mutate a tuple, you made a new one.

```
>>> tup = (1, 2, 3)
>>> tup2 = tup
>>> tup
(1, 2, 3)
>>> tup2
(1, 2, 3)
>>> tup += (4, 5)
>>> tup
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> tup2
(1, 2, 3)
```

Initially, `tup` and `tup2` refer to the same tuple. After the `tup += (4, 5)`, `tup` refers to a new tuple and `tup2` still refers to the old one. No mutation occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable which means you cannot update or change the values of tuple elements. You are able to take portions of existing tuples to create new tuples.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `+=` sneakily stops being an in-place operator. `tuple` is a different tuple from when you started, because adding two tuples necessarily produces a new one, because tuples are immutable.